# Recognize the OWL type in a file

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

I receive a OWL file with a formalized ontology. See the header below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>


<!DOCTYPE Ontology [
    <!ENTITY xsd "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" >
    <!ENTITY xml "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" >
    <!ENTITY rdfs "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" >
    <!ENTITY rdf "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" >
   ]>


<Ontology xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xml:base="http://ibilce.university.br/OntoFSER"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
     ontologyIRI="http://ibilce.university.br/OntoFSER"
     versionIRI="http://ibilce.university.br/OntoFSER/1.0.0">
    <Prefix name="" IRI="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"/>
    <Prefix name="owl" IRI="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"/>
    <Prefix name="rdf" IRI="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"/>
    <Prefix name="xsd" IRI="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"/>
    <Prefix name="rdfs" IRI="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"/>
```

Exists some way to discover if this document is a OWL-Lite, OWL-DL or OWL-Full document just with the file? I did not see any information about this in the headers (namespaces or something like this).

If not, is it possible to discover this information loading this file in Protegé for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protege will show you the DL language used. The OWL API has various profile checkers (see the `Profiles` enumeration) that can verify if an ontology belongs to a profile or not.

Note that it is possible that an ontology belongs to, for example, OWL 2 EL, but it can import ontologies that are in OWL 2 DL - a reasoner would see this ontology as an OWL 2 DL ontology.